# Changing tour bounce altitude on Google Earth Web API

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

During a tour using a KML file, is there a way to specify the bounce altitude or height? For example, I want it to zoom out all the way to the continent level before flying into another location (which is in another continent). Is it possible to regulate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "smooth" [flyToMode](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxflytomode) instead of the default "bounce" to first fly to the continent level (you can also set the speed).  Then use a second bounce (or smooth) flyTo to get to your destination from there.